# Can't use Exporter properly

Tags: perl, exporter

I've wasted many days on a larger block of code, containing `Exporter` statements, which used to work about a year ago. Several variations on this have failed, including an install of `./FOO/BAR/Foobar.pm` which signaled success.

I am using Windows 10, Perl v5.26.0, built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

#### Caller.pl

```perl
   #!/usr/bin/perl

   use lib ".";
   use lib "./FOO/BAR";

   use strict;
   use warnings;

   use FOO::BAR::Foobar;

   print "try FOO::BAR::Foobar::foo()\n";
   FOO::BAR::Foobar::foo();  # perl can't find this

   print "try foo()\n";
   foo();          # errors out - can't find &main::foo

   print "done\n";
```

#### ./FOO/BAR/Foobar.pl

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

package Foobar;

our($VERSION , @ISA , @EXPORT , @EXPORT_OK , %EXPORT_TAGS , $FOO);

BEGIN {
    require Exporter;
    @ISA       = qw(Exporter);
    @EXPORT_OK = qw(foo);
}

sub foo {
    print "Loaded\n";
    $FOO = q{some val};
}

1;
```

#### Execution dump

```
perl Caller.pl
try FOO::BAR::Foobar::foo()
Undefined subroutine &FOO::BAR::Foobar::foo called at Caller.pl line 12.
```

What's going on? Should I abandon any use of `Exporter`? But then how to link functions across modules?

Comment: Try replacing `package Foobar` with `package FOO::BAR::Foobar` at the top of the file `./FOO/BAR/Foobar.pl`

Comment: It's worth pointing out that a module file is normally never run, so the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/perl -w` is just a comment and should be removed.

Comment: *"I've wasted many days on a larger block of code, containing Exporter statements, which used to work about a year ago"* It's not very becoming to try to blame stuff on a bug in Perl, which is way less likely than a mistake on your part. That "larger block of code" would still run if you hadn't changed it, and that's one of the first things you should have tried, "many days" ago.

Comment: Tip: `.` is the CWD, not necessary the script's directory. Since you want the script's directory, use `$RealBin` instead (after doing `use FindBin qw( $RealBin );`). e.g. `use FindBin qw( $RealBin ); use lib $RealBin, "$RealBin/FOO/BAR";`

Answer (score 4):

There are three things going wrong:

1. With `FOO::BAR::Foobar::foo()`: There is no such `sub`, there is only `Foobar::foo()`.
2. With `foo()`: `use FOO::BAR::Foobar;` is the equivalent of `BEGIN { require FOO::BAR::Foobar; FOO::BAR::Foobar->import() }`, but there is no method `import` available in the package `FOO::BAR::Foobar`, since you're inheriting `Exporter` into the package `Foobar`.
3. With `foo()`: You're using `@EXPORT_OK` instead of `@EXPORT`, which means that you need to explicitly import `foo`, but you're not doing that in `use FOO::BAR::Foobar;`.

So two things are needed to fix this:

1. As already pointed out in the comment by @HåkonHægland, change `package Foobar;` to `package FOO::BAR::Foobar;`.
2. Change `use FOO::BAR::Foobar;` to `use FOO::BAR::Foobar qw/foo/;`.

Then the code you've shown will work - there's no need to abandon [`Exporter`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html). I'd just recommend a different style of using `Exporter`: Instead of inheriting via `@ISA`, just import `import` into your package. Here's how I would have written your file `./FOO/BAR/Foobar.pm`:

```
package FOO::BAR::Foobar;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(foo);

our $FOO;
sub foo {
    print "Loaded\n";
    $FOO = q{some val};
}

1;
```

Comment: 1. and 2. are basically both *"Your package and file has the wrong name"*. `require Exporter` is fine as long as `@ISA = qw(Exporter)` is also there. I also notice that the OP says that the package is in `./FOO/BAR/Foobar.pl` (instead of `.pm`) which won't work at all.

Comment: @Borodin Yes, they are, hence only one solution for both - it was my answer to the OP's question *"What's going on?"*. I assumed the `Foobar.pl` was just a typo, since later on in the post the correct file is named, and otherwise the OP would have seen a different error message, but you're right to point it out.

Comment: @Borodin As for `@ISA=("Exporter");`, yes, it's an acceptable method - it's just that the package will inherit all the other methods from `Exporter` too, even though most modules only need `import`, hence my suggestion to `use Exporter 'import';`.

Comment: Okay. I was confused about your point 2. You seemed to be implying that `require Exporter` was incorrect. And I do agree that `use Exporter 'import'` is preferable, but not for the reason you say: a module should be *either* a library (when `Exporter` is fine used either way) or an OO module (when `Exporter` is irrelevant) and not both.